# Linux find folders without files but only subfolders

Tags: linux, command-line

I know that empty folders can be found using:

```
find DirectoryPath -type d -empty
```

I would like to find folders without files but that may have one or more subfolders (also not empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following command (`DirPath` is the dir to be searched):

```
find DirPath -type d -exec bash -c '[ "x`find "{}" -maxdepth 1 -type f`" = x ] && echo "{}"' \;
```

A brief explanation:

- `-type d`: check only directories.
- `-exec bash -c CMD1 \;` run the command CMD using each of the checked directories. We need to use the shell because CMD1 is a lsit of commands.
- `[ "x`CMD2`" = x ] && echo "{}"`: runs the command CMD2 and, if the output is empty it will echo the name of the directory.
- `find "{}" -maxdepth 1 -type f`: Look for any file in the current directory.

Putting it together: it will print the name of the directories in which there are no files.

Comment: seems to have problem with folders with a space in the name: find: "./Applicazioni/Static": File o directory non esistente
find: "Web": File o directory non esistente
find: "Apps": File o directory non esistente

here the folder is "Static Web Apps"

Comment: @MatteoPagliazzi: Oh, darn! A few quotes here and there and solved! It may still fail with directories with quotes or other weird characters, but hey! for a full proper solution you should use a real programming language.